# Assigning projections in loop using R?

Tags: r, point-in-polygon

I'm using R to do some geospatial analysis.

Basically, I am trying to solve for a method of doing poly.counts when my data is too large for my laptop (and R complains about the matrix being too large).

If I have a table I have geocoded, I know I can assign a projection by using

```
proj4string(my_list_of_things) <- CRS("+init=epsg:26978")
```

If I wanted to use a for loop in R (gasp!) to pull out a subset (as I have a large amount of data for my puny computer), I am doing something like:

```
for (i in c(2000) )
{
  print(paste("Postcode: ", i))

  # this subsets things correctly
  a.nam <- paste("subset.",i,sep="") 
  assign(a.nam, my_list_of_things[my_list_of_things$postcode == i,])

  #now is the weird bit
  b.nam <- paste("proj4string(subset.", i, sep = "")
  c.nam <- paste(b.nam, ")", sep="")
  # it prints it correctly
  print(c.nam)

  # this bit doesn't work as I expect
  assign(c.nam, CRS("+init=epsg:26978") )

  # I then want to go on and do something like 
  nam <- paste("intersections.",i,sep="")
  assign(nam, poly.counts(c.nam, sometable) )
  # to get the number of incidents in the postcode (defined by c.nam) in 
  # the overall regions (in sometable) 
}
```

So it prints correctly, but the expectation that within each loop it would run

```
proj4string(subset.2000) <- CRS("init=epsg:26978")
```

However it seems to run something equivalent to

```
'proj4string(subset.2000)' <- CRS("init=epsg:26978")
```

So instead of 'fixing' the projection for each subset, it creates a variable with a projection defined and the data is "unprojected".

Does that make sense, and if so, how do I solve it?

---

Based on the example by @SpacedMan, the following example exemplifies my problem:

```
z = data.frame(w=1:10, x=1:10, y=1:10, z=letters[1:10])
coordinates(z)=~x+y

for (i in c(1) )
{
  message("Postcode: ", i)
  a.nam <- paste("subset.",i,sep="") 
  assign(a.nam, z[z$w == i,])

  #now is the weird bit
  b.nam <- paste("proj4string(subset.", i, sep = "")
  c.nam <- paste(b.nam, ")", sep="")
  # it prints it correctly
  print(c.nam)

  # this bit doesn't work as I expect
  assign(c.nam, CRS("+init=epsg:26978") )

}
```

I'd expect the last "assign" to correct assign the correct projection to, in this instance, subset.1

---

So even following @SpacedMan's advice and using [i] notation, I have an issue, albeit another one.

```
for(i in c(1))
{
  test[i] = z[z$w == i]
  proj4string(test[i]) <- CRS("+init=epsg:26978")
}
```

so in this instance the test object isn't assigned before entering the loop. However I don't know what I should try creating it as, as something like

```
test <- list()
```

before the loop throws up an error.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Any R function of the form `foo(x) = bar` is sort of rewritten internally as `x = "foo<-"(x, bar)` to get it back to a purer functional form that updates `x`. You can actually use `foo<-` as a function. So the following are equivalent:

```
proj4string(x) = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
x = "proj4string<-"(x, CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
```

That "syntactic sugar" form of the first line saves a bit of typing and looks neater, but under the hood R is doing the second line. Note now there's a simple R object on the LHS of the `=`.... Let's see this in action:

Sample data:

```
> z = data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10, z=letters[1:10])
> coordinates(z)=~x+y
```

The name of the thing we want to change is `z` - store this name in `what`:

```
> what="z"
```

To update `z` via assign to the value in `what`, using the `proj4string<-` function, you do:

```
> assign(what, "proj4string<-"(get(what),CRS("+init=epsg:27700")))
> proj4string(z)
[1] "+init=epsg:27700 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894"
```

and to check that works, let's do it again with a different CRS:

```
> assign(what, "proj4string<-"(get(what),CRS("+init=epsg:4326")))
Warning message:
[blah blah about not reprojecting]
> proj4string(z)
[1] "+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

At this point you should start to think that assigning to names is a bad idea, and you should store things in a list data structure, and then index it with `[[i]]`. Much much neater.

Bonus tip - instead of:

```
  print(paste("Postcode: ", i))
```

try:

```
  message("Postcode: ",i)
```

Comment: +1, terrific look under the hood. Not sure I follow about why assigning to names = bad though?

Comment: Its an unstructured mess, that's why. If you create things named `foo.1` up to `foo.1000` then you'll be forever writing get/assign. Create a list with `foo[[1]]` up to `foo[[1000]]` then you've got *one* object in your workspace *and* you can do `foo[[i]]=` in a loop, and use `lapply`-constructs.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your awesome response and quick and dirty example, I fleshed out an example. Note: the proj4string(subset.2000) <- CRS("init=epsg:26978") works outside the loop, but not inside.

Comment: @Spacedman got it - hadn't referred back to the structures in original question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that:

```
proj4string(my_list_of_things) <- CRS("+init=epsg:26978")
```

is failing? A Spatial*DataFrame object in R has a proj4string slot, but (unlike in PostGIS tables, for example), the CRS is not stored in each individual geometry, only the coordinates are. So I would be very surprised to hear that this statement is failing regardless of the size of the Spatial*DataFrame.

Furthermore, the `assign` function is returning a variable, because that's what the `assign` statement does. It allows you to specify a variable name as a string. You have oddly chosen to build a string that looks like a function call, but it is still a variable. Please refer to the [`assign`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/assign) documentation. You seem to want it to behave like [`eval`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/eval).

On the other hand, it is not surprising that if your points layer and polygons layer are large that the `poly.count` function would choke. In particular, I would note that since GISTools is a pedagogical package, the functions may not be properly optimized, and you should attempt to implement it yourself.

But this isn't the question you are asking. Please test to see whether you can assign the proj4string outside of an R loop, and if that problem is taken care of please create new question regarding how to implement a point-in-polygon count

Comment: I can do both the projection and the poly count outside the loop. Doing it within a loop is my issue.